# Setting the style parameters for all similar tds in html table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am trying to set similar style for all tds in an html table like below:

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: right; direction: ltr;">1</td>
<td style="text-align: right; direction: ltr;">2</td>
<td style="text-align: right; direction: ltr;">3</td>
.
.
.
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Is there a way I can define the text within all these tds to be aligned right and directed to the left without the need of repeating the same for each cell? I know I can do this in a css file by somehow defining an Id or class, but is there a way I can do it within the same html file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following css will apply text align to all cells of all tables on your page. if you want it to be individually per table, set the table an ID or Class and apply the following code to it:

```
table td{
    text-align: right;
}
```

to include it in the same html file, simply add it within a style block in your head section of the html:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    .MyTable td {
      width:100px;
      border:1px solid purple;
      text-align: right !important; /*this attribute will be forced*/
      direction: ltr;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <table class="MyTable">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can I use this method in a Wordpress post?

Comment: @developer this is standard css, you can use it anywhere and everywhere.  you only need to watch out for other css/javascript that might override your class styles, or apply an `!important` after each css attribute before the semicolon to force it.

Comment: I just tried the above code in a wordpress post, but, for some reason, the "head" and "style" tags are removed when I add them in text mode.

Comment: @developer wordpress creates the head tags for you. you need to find the function that renders the head section, and add the style there.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `class="right"` to your `<td>` elements and then define the following CSS class:

```
.right {
    text-align: right;
}
```

You can rename the class and/or add any other properties (like `direction` etc.).

If you wish to make this without any additional markups in your HTML code, you can create the following CSS class:

```
table td:nth-child(2) {
    text-align: right;
}
```

This will align your 2nd column in your table to the right. If you wish to change the column number, just change the number in the parasintesis.